# Variable in string literal nim

Tags: xml, nim-lang

I am trying to use a variable within .writefile

example i have

```
echo readLineFromStdin("enter cluster id: ")
    var line: string

/etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/custom.xml".writefile("""<yandex>
     <listen_host>0.0.0.0</listen_host>
     <server_num>Variable goes here</server_num>
    <logger>
```

What would be the best way to do this? i have tried looking into string literals on
https://nim-lang.org/docs/strformat.html

I have also tried putting it like

```
<servername>", clusterid, "</servername>
```

any ideas would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can either concatenate the string with `&` (and convert things to string with `$`). Or you can look into the https://nim-lang.org/docs/strformat.html module in the standard library.